# Sonata - Implement a form inside the show template

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I need to implement a form inside my show template of a specific admin. In the original demo of Symfony a great example is shown. Please take a look at it here;

1. [Controller](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo/blob/master/src/AppBundle/Controller/BlogController.php#L83) (look at the method on line 120 as well)
2. [Post Show template](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo/blob/master/app/Resources/views/blog/post_show.html.twig#L18)
3. [Comment Form template](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo/blob/master/app/Resources/views/blog/_comment_form.html.twig)

---

**Now what I've done in Sonata;**

I've created the custom CRUD Controller for the specific admin class (OrderAdmin). I already have a clone action there that works well, so I know my custom CRUD Controller works perfect.

I also have a custom show template specific for OrderAdmin. Again that works well, because I already have something custom there.

Now for my work relating to this custom comment form;

My **action** just to render the form (like in the Symfony demo):

```
/**
 * @param Order $order
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function commentFormAction(Order $order)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('comment')
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Order:_comment_form.html.twig', array(
        'order' => $order,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

A snippet of my **show template**:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            {{ render(controller('AppBundle:OrderCRUD:commentForm', { 'id': object.id })) }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

and finally **my _comment_form template** where the form self is rendered:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">Comment</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

I'm pretty sure this is all setup fine, the only problem I get is that...

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("There is no `_sonata_admin` defined for the controller
>   `AppBundle\Controller\OrderCRUDController` and the
>   current route ``").

I have another action that will be the comment form action, but I get the problem here before that action is called on form submission.

Can somebody please help me understand this `_sonata_admin`. How do I define it? What should I had to my code, or how do I have to change it to get a form function properly in my show template. Does anybody have an example of how to accomplish this? I've come across a few posts over the web where people struggle with this.

I've also started a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635044/adding-a-custom-form-inside-the-show-template-of-a-sonata-admin-entity) with a very very similar issue.

I desperately need help to get this to work. Please? I know Sonata support is quite poor but I need you guys, please.

Comment: You should debug [this line](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/240ecbd02d453f9acaf81e00112ff5d8dae4459b/Route/RouteCollection.php#L87), see if its executed for your custom route

Comment: Ok, and what if it's not executed? What do I have to do then?

Comment: I'd check the `configureRoutes` method of the admin. The method is supposed to be called here.

Comment: After googling on '_sonata_admin' the past week or two, I just 'accidentally' come across this line: `{{ render(controller("XxxxBundle:XxxxCRUS:xxxx", {'xx': object.xx, '_sonata_admin' : 'sonata.admin.xxxx'})) }}`. It seems like it fixed it! Now how am I suppose to know about this?

Comment: This looks more like a workaround. I think I already wrote custom actions myself and didn't need to do that.

Comment: IMO the problem has to do with the only thing you don't show : the routing part of your problem. See the docs : https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/cookbook/recipe_custom_action.html#bringing-it-all-together

Comment: I have another custom action, also a clone action, and with that one I have no problem whatsoever. I've followed that cookbook and it worked. But now with this action it doesn't want to work, I keep on getting the mentioned error. I have the route configured in `configuredRoutes()`, and if I modify the URL accordingly it works, no problem with that. But the issue is that the action doesn't want to render in my show template with this `{{ render(controller('AppBundle:OrderCRUD:comment')) }}`. And then if I add this part `{ '_sonata_admin': 'sonata.admin.pmod_order' }` does work.

Comment: Oh right, and there is no routing involved at this point. The routing provides this argument. Maybe make a PR to document that?

Comment: Ok, will try that, still pretty new to all this, because of that the faulty issue on github (should have payed more attention to the rules).

Comment: So I guess the best way to render an action is to do this 'workaround' by adding `{ '_sonata_admin': 'sonata.admin.pmod_order' }`?

Comment: I think so too…

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, greg0ire. I appreciate it a lot.